# how to make shapel auto display when use plotshape?

Tags: pine-script

Icon will overlap If has much shapes when use plotshape.such as [image]

so Can I make these shapes auto dispaly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to position each one explicitly at a different price level using the `location.absolute` argument to the `location` parameter. When using `location.absolute`, the first parameter of the function, `series`, must contain the y position of your shape on the chart: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_plotshape